# Insert Material-UI Icon into Input Field in React

Tags: html, reactjs, input, icons, material-ui

Hi I am using a datepicker from Material-UI Datepickers. 
Using the Inline datepickers they provide I want to insert a calendar Icon into the input field.

this is what the input element looks like. How can I add an I con to the input field here. So that it still shows inside the element and clicking it will activate the inputfield but will not disrupt the value of the input.

```
              <InlineDatePicker
                label={"Start Date"}
                value={startDate}
                format={"MMM Do YYYY"}
                onChange={(e) => {this.handleDateChange(e, 'start')}}
                className={styles.dateInput}
                minDate={this.getMinDate(true)}
                maxDate={this.getMaxDate(true)}
              />
```

Answer (score 4):

So I figured out that you can pass props down to the textfield of the datepicker. 
So to achieve what I was trying to achieve you disable keyboard mode and set up the inline Datepicker like this

```
              <InlineDatePicker
                value={date}
                onChange={(e) => {this.handleDateChange(e)}}
                InputProps={{
                  endAdornment: (
                  <InputAdornment position={'end'}>
                    <Icon>
                      <CalendarToday />
                    </Icon>
                  </InputAdornment>)
                }}
              />
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure the exact answer to your question, but here's a very related material-ui datepicker that you could use: https://codesandbox.io/s/yp4nr9nvkj

Comment: Unfortunately I need to use the inlineDatepickers in the material-ui library